# SQL Comma separated values comparisons

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a challenge comparing values in `Available` column with values in `Required` column. They are both comma separated.

| Available | Required | Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One, Two, Three | One, Three | 1 |
| One, Three | Three, Five | 0 |
| One, Two, Three | Two | 1 |

What I want to achieve is, if values in the `Required` column are all found in the `Available` column then it gives me a match of `1` and `0` if one or more values that are in the `Required` column is missing in the `Available` column

I want to achieve this in SQL.

Comment: Yeah I corrected it. Since Five is missing in the Available column, then there's no match

Comment: have you tried using [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Comment: I  *really* recommend fixing your design here; don't store delimited data in your database at all.

Comment: Are you able to change the table structure? Because as you can see, storing delimited lists turns what should be a simple query into something more convoluted than it needs to be...

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, an approach based on `STRING_SPLIT()` and an appropriate `JOIN` is an option:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data 
FROM (VALUES
   ('One, Two, Three', 'One, Three'),
   ('One, Three',      'Three, Five'),
   ('One, Two, Three', 'Two')
) v (Available, Required)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Available, Required,
   CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM STRING_SPLIT(Required, ',') s1
         LEFT JOIN STRING_SPLIT(Available, ',') s2 ON TRIM(s1.[value]) = TRIM(s2.[value])
         WHERE s2.[value] IS NULL      
      ) THEN 0
      ELSE 1
   END AS Match
FROM Data
```

Result:

| Available | Required | Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One, Two, Three | One, Three | 1 |
| One, Three | Three, Five | 0 |
| One, Two, Three | Two | 1 |

Comment: @tapiwajemwa, if you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Zhorov's solution.

It is using a set based operator `EXCEPT`.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Available VARCHAR(100), Required VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Available, Required) VALUES
('One, Two, Three', 'One, Three'),
('One, Three',      'Three, Five'),
('One, Two, Three', 'Two');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
   , [Match] = CASE
      WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT TRIM([value]) FROM STRING_SPLIT(Required, ',')
        EXCEPT
        SELECT TRIM([value]) FROM STRING_SPLIT(Available, ',')
      ) THEN 0
      ELSE 1
   END
FROM @tbl AS t;
```

**Output**

```
+-----------------+-------------+-------+
|    Available    |  Required   | Match |
+-----------------+-------------+-------+
| One, Two, Three | One, Three  |     1 |
| One, Three      | Three, Five |     0 |
| One, Two, Three | Two         |     1 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a cross join to look in all available values, your query would be :

```
    SELECT t.*
    ,case when SUM(CASE 
        WHEN t1.Available LIKE '%' + t.Required + '%'
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) > 0  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [Match_Calculated]
FROM YOUR_TABLE t
CROSS JOIN YOUR_TABLE  t1
GROUP BY t.Available
    ,t.Required
    ,t.Match
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa2459727e56b682dd30e59d3b2c674d)

Comment: It's curious that your code finds a match between `'Onesy, Two, fThree'` `Available` and `'One, Three'` `Required` when they have no common list elements. Aside: You could replace the `case` around the `sum` with [`sign`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sign-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "STRING_SPLIT" to achieve your request

```
;with Source as 
(
    select 1 id,'One,Two,Three' Available,'One,Three' Required
    union all
    select 2 id,'One,Three' Available,'Three,Five' Required
    union all
    select 3 id,'One,Two,Three' Available,'Two' Required
)
,AvailableTmp as 
(
    SELECT t.id,
            x.value
       FROM Source t
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT trim(value) value
                                FROM string_split(t.Available, ',')) x
)
,RequiredTmp as 
(
SELECT t.id,
       x.value
       FROM Source t
            CROSS APPLY (SELECT trim(value) value
                                FROM string_split(t.Required, ',')) x
)
,AllMatchTmp as 
(
select a.id
        ,1 Match
    From RequiredTmp a 
        left join AvailableTmp b on a.id=b.id and a.value = b.value 
    group by a.id
    having max(case when b.value is null then 1 else 0 end ) = 0
)
select a.id
        ,a.Available
        ,a.Required
        ,ISNULL(b.Match,0) Match
    from Source a
        left join AllMatchTmp b on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `STRING_SPLIT`

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (Available VARCHAR(100), [Required] VARCHAR(100), 
                       INDEX IX_data(Available,[Required]));
INSERT @data 
VALUES ('One, Two, Three', 'One, Three'),('One, Three', 'Three, Five'),
       ('One, Two, Three', 'Two');

SELECT
  Available  = d.Available,
  [Required] = d.[Required],
  [Match]    = MIN(f.X)
FROM        @data                                          AS d
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(d.[Required],' ',''),',') AS split
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(REPLACE(d.[Available],' ','')))        AS cleaned(String)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(IIF(split.[value] NOT IN 
              (SELECT s.[value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(cleaned.String,',') AS s),0,1))) AS f(X)
GROUP BY    d.Available, d.[Required];
```